# Add Columns dynamically to Grid-view with itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, gridview, itemtemplate

i want to know how to add column dynmically to gridview. the grid view suppose to get user input. i know how to use itemtemplate for specific no of columns, but i'm not aware how to add columns dynamically with itemtemplate (textbox) fields and make databind.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a class implementing **ITemplate** , Full code as following:

```
public class DynamicTemplateField : ITemplate
{

    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        //define the control to be added , i take text box as your need
        TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
        txt1.ID = "txt1";
        container.Controls.Add(txt1);
    }
}

//Method to bind the Grid View
public void BindData()
{
    TemplateField temp1  = new TemplateField();  //Create instance of Template field
    temp1.HeaderText = "New Dynamic Temp Field"; //Give the header text

    temp1.ItemTemplate = new DynamicTemplateField(); //Set the properties **ItemTemplate** as the instance of DynamicTemplateField class.


    gv.Columns.Add(temp1); //add the instance if template field in columns of grid view

    //Bind the grid  view
    gv.DataSource = [your data source];
    gv.DataBind();

 }
```

**RowDataBound**

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
      TextBox txt1 = e.Row.FindControl("txt1") as TextBox;
      txt1.Text = e.Row.DataItem["Name"]; //Assign any column value of your datasource
    }

}
```

**.aspx page**

```
<asp:GridView ID = "gv" runat = "server"  >
    <Columns>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You can manipulate **DynamicTemplateField** class to add different types of control

Comment: dynamic column added, fine. but how do you make the binding for each itemtemplate and add new rows in this approach ?

Comment: Use RowDataBound event to assign value to dynamic added controls, Posted answer is edited accordingly

Comment: how to fire textbox change event and save from code-behind?

Comment: txt1.Text = e.Row.DataItem["TestLbl"]; //Assign any column value of your datasource I get the error  -- Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type object