# Change WebGrid cell into textbox form

Tags: c#, razor, webgrid, asp.net-webpages

I have a dataset and I'm required to display it in a Web Application. Here is what the dataset looks like:

```
Point_ID    Project No.    Project Manager    Comments
A007        1304           Oscar Duran        Found destroyed
A008        1304           Oscar Duran        Helicopter access
A009        1356           Julio Bravo        Airport parking lot
```

Here is what I have for my code:

```
@{
var db = Database.Open("ControlPoints");                                            
var SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM AllControlMergedWD";                       
var SearchTerm = "";                                                                

if(!Request.QueryString["SearchCP"].IsEmpty() ){                                    
    SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM AllControlMergedWD WHERE Point_ID = @0";         
    SearchTerm = Request.QueryString["SearchCP"];                                   
}

if(!Request.QueryString["SearchProject"].IsEmpty() ){                               
    SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM AllControlMergedWD WHERE [Project Used on] LIKE @0";
    SearchTerm = "%" + Request["SearchProject"] + "%";
}

var SelectData = db.Query(SelectCommand, SearchTerm);                               
var grid = new WebGrid(source: SelectData, rowsPerPage: 10);                        
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Airborne Imaging Control Points Database</title>

    <style type="text/css"> 
        .grid { margin: 4px; border-collapse: collapse; width: 600px; }
        .grid th, .grid td { border: 1px solid #C0C0C0; padding: 5px; }
        .head { background-color: #E8E8E8; font-weight: bold; color: #FFF; }
        .alt { background-color: #E8E8E8; color: #000; }                                  
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Airborne Imaging Control Points Database</h1><br/><br/>                             
    <form method="get">
        <fieldset>                                                                  
            <legend>Search Criteria</legend>                                        
            <div>
                <p><label for="SearchCP">Control Point ID:</label>                   
                <input type="text" name="SearchCP" value="@Request.QueryString["SearchCP"]" placeholder="Leave blank to list all"/> 
                <input type="submit" value="Search"/></p>                               
            </div>
            <div>
                <p><label for="SearchProject">Project:</label>                          
                <input type="text" name="SearchProject" value="@Request.QueryString["SearchProject"]" />
                <input type="Submit" value="Search" /></p>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(                                                          
            tableStyle: "grid",                                                 
            headerStyle: "head",                                                
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",                                         
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("Point_ID"),
                grid.Column("Project No."),
                grid.Column("Project Manager"),
                grid.Column("Comments", format: @<text>@Html.TextBox("Comments")</text>)
            )
        )
        <br/><br/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I have been trying to do is turning the 'Comments' cells into form elements (text box), so that anybody with access to the Application will be able to add comments, edit or update statuses of the current condition of the points. Could you please help me achieving that?

Thank you beforehand.

**UPDATE**

I was able to add the text box field in the 'Comments' column (I have updated my code above). Now what I have left is saving the comments that are entered into the database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Columns dynamically to Grid-view with itemtemplate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592785/add-columns-dynamically-to-grid-view-with-itemtemplate)

Comment: I was trying to apply the answer in the link you posted, but I don't think it applies to asp.net Web Pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to solve my problem. Here is the modifications I have made to my *WebGrid*:

```
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml(                                                                      
            tableStyle: "grid",                                                             
            headerStyle: "head",                                                            
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",                                                     
            columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("", format: @<text>
                    <button class="edit-comment display-mode" id="@item.Point_ID">Edit</button>         
                    <button class="save-comment edit-mode" id="@item.Point_ID">Save</button> </text>),
                grid.Column("Point_ID", "Point ID"),
                grid.Column("Project No.", "Project No"),
                grid.Column("Project Used on"),
                grid.Column("WGS84 Lat"),
                grid.Column("WGS84 Long"),
                grid.Column("Ellips_Ht"),
                grid.Column("Project Manager"),
                grid.Column("Comments", format: @<text>
                    <span id="comments" class="display-mode">@item.Comments</span>                              
                    @Html.TextBox("Comments", item.Comments, new {@class="edit-mode", size = 45}) </text>)      
            )
        )
        <br/><br/>
    </div>
```

As you can see, I added a new column to hold the buttons, and to the *Comments* column I added a span and a form. Next, I added the following script to toggle between modes and add events to the buttons:

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('.edit-mode').hide();                                 
            $('.edit-comment').on('click', function () {            
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');               
                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();      
            });
            $('.save-comment').on('click', function () {            
                var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');               
                var point_ID = $(this).prop('id');                  
                var comments = tr.find('#Comments').val();          
                $.post(
                    '/EditComments',
                    { Point_ID: point_ID, Comments: comments },     
                    function (updatespan) {
                        tr.find('#comments').text(updatespan.Comments);   
                    }, "json");
                tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();      
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Finally, I created *EditComments*, which updates the database and retrieves back the update for display:

```
@{  
    var point_ID = Request["Point_ID"];                     
    var comments = Request["Comments"];                     
    var db = Database.Open("ControlPoints");                
    var sql = "UPDATE AllControlMergedND SET Comments = @0 WHERE Point_ID = @1";
    db.Execute(sql, comments, point_ID);                    

    sql = @"SELECT * FROM AllControlMergedND WHERE Point_ID = @0";
    var result = db.QuerySingle(sql, point_ID);             
    Json.Write(result, Response.Output);                    
}
```

All of this I was able to do thanks to a blog post I found in the following link:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/202/inline-editing-with-the-webgrid

The procedures are very well explained in the blog.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the format of a WebGrid column

```
<div>
    @grid.GetHtml(                                                          
        tableStyle: "grid",                                                 
        headerStyle: "head",                                                
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",                                         
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Point_ID"),
            grid.Column("Project No."),
            grid.Column("Project Manager"),
            grid.Column("Comments", @<text>@Html.TextBox("Comments")</text>)
        )
    )
    <br/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, your solution worked very well when I modified it to the following: `grid.Column("Comments", format: @<text>@Html.TextBox("Comments")</text>)`. Now I am able to see the text box and write in it, but I am not able to save the comments into the database. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Oscar, to save the comments into the Database is another question which isn't easy to answer. You can mark my answer as resolved and ask another question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would definitely mark this answer, but it didn't resolve all the problems presented.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey Oscar you asked me to provide you with an answer...**

I do not code asp.net razor this way.  In my opinion you should learn how to code it using Models, Views, and Controllers.  What you have here is a very bad practice. One file with everything in it is not good to do.

But to answer your question specifically... I will point you to this tutorial which shows how to do what you want with a webgrid.

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2727/using-webgrid-to-populate-data-as-gridview-in-aspnet-mvc-razorview

Comment: He's not using MVC.  He's using [ASP.Net Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages).  Although I don't disagree, using MVC is under most circumstances is superior to Web Pages.

Comment: Answers should be self contained and not rely on links to external websites. If that link ever breaks, the solution to this problem will be lost for anyone else that finds this question. You should include the relevant information from the link in your answer.

Comment: I know i should but he asked me for an answer specifically...  so i provided him an answer...

Comment: Hello all, thanks for your time, particularly Phillip for answering my help request. I am not familiar with MVC and it would take me a while to learn it. I have a limited amount of time, so I am more likely not going to learn it, but I might if I find no other way to solve my problem.