# ASP.net GridView in C# programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sharepoint

**Hello, everyone! I need below ASPX code transform to C# code for Class Libraby solution. My problem is with ItemTemplate where add TextBox Controll :**

[image]

```
    <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

**in C# format like below code:**

```
 public class HelloWorldWeb : WebPart
    {
        private SPGridView myGrid;

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            myGrid = new SPGridView();
            myGrid.ShowFooter = true;
            myGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            myGrid.ID = "Gridview1";

            SPBoundField dest = new SPBoundField();
            dest.DataField = "RowNumber";
            dest.HeaderText = "Row Number";
            TemplateField headerOne = new TemplateField();
            headerOne.HeaderText = "Header 1";
            this.myGrid.Columns.Add(dest);
```

Comment: What's the issue here? Could you please be more clear?

Comment: I write code in Class Library solution. Need ASPX code in C#

Comment: What do you want to do with that? specify it.

Comment: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-new-Row-to-GridView-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx I need this for C# Class Library.

Comment: Your answer is in the link you provided.  You do not add and delete rows to a GridView control.  You make changes to a backing datasource.  Since you want to do this programmatically, a common construct is the `DataTable`.  You use `DataTable` class methods to build your table, rows and columns in the code behind. Then assign the `DataTable` to the Gridview and then call  the GridView's `DataBind()`

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592785/add-columns-dynamically-to-grid-view-with-itemtemplate