# dynamically add itemplate to the gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have created gridview. Added a textbox to specify what number of columns user want to add to the grid dynamically and its done successfully.

I want to add text box to the dynamically added fields to enter the data and save it to the database(I am able to add text fields to the rows and save data) but i didnt got any solution yet.

I have tried with itemplate but I don't know much about it. i have added my code below.
Here is my aspx code

```
                        <input type="hidden" runat="server" value="0" id="columnAdded"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>




<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <%--<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />--%>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S. No.">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblsno"  runat="server" Text='<%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbInsert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Parts" DataField="parts">

            </asp:BoundField>

         <%--<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder_InputControl" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>--%>

        <%--<asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnedit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="EditRow"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>--%>

        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and here is .cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            drpstation.Items.Clear();

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from stationdesc where stndesc <> '' and id is not null";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(ds, "stationdesc");

            drpstation.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            drpstation.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["stndesc"].ColumnName.ToString();
            drpstation.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["id"].ColumnName.ToString();
            drpstation.DataBind();
            drpstation.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Station", "0"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string Msg = "select station error";
            Msg += ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        griddisplay();


    }
}
public void griddisplay()
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM stnparts", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //dt.Columns.Add("Parts", typeof(string));
        //DataRow drr = dt.NewRow();
        //drr["Parts"] = "Weldmet";
        //dt.Rows.Add(drr);

        //drr = dt.NewRow();
        //drr["Parts"] = "MFG Parts";
        //dt.Rows.Add(drr);

        //GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        //GridView1.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception d)
    {
        string message = "grid error";
        message += d.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num;
    num = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumber.Text.Trim());
    int addedColumn = Convert.ToInt32(columnAdded.Value);
    for (int i = addedColumn + 1; i <= addedColumn + num; i++)
    {
        string name = "Unit";
        name = string.Concat(name, i);
        TemplateField test = new TemplateField();
        test.HeaderText = name;
        GridView1.Columns.Add(test);
        TextBox txtname = new TextBox();
        string txtunit = "txtunit";
        txtname.ID = txtunit + i;

    }
    griddisplay();
    columnAdded.Value = (addedColumn + num).ToString();
}

public class TemplateHandler : ITemplate
{


    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();

        txtbox.Text = "test";
        txtbox.DataBinding += Txtbox_Binding;
        container.Controls.Add(txtbox);

    }

    private void Txtbox_Binding(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        TextBox txttest = (TextBox)sender;
        GridViewRow container = (GridViewRow)txttest.NamingContainer;
        //txttest.Text = ((TableNameClass)container.DataItem).SkillText;
        ((DataRowView)container.DataItem)["SkillText"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: You said: "I am able to add text fields to the rows and save data". So what is the problem you are facing then?

Comment: My columns are dynamic, I can add the text fields if columns are static in gridview.

Comment: I hope question is clear now

Comment: I can see `TemplateHandler` class and you are in right direction. Go through and Try this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592785/add-columns-dynamically-to-grid-view-with-itemtemplate) and get back with exact problem you are facing.

Comment: I have tried this answer still I will it once again

Comment: Check my answer if that help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a pseudo/sample code(not tested!) based on the code you posted, to give you some heads-up

```
protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num;
    num = Convert.ToInt32(txtnumber.Text.Trim());
    int addedColumn = Convert.ToInt32(columnAdded.Value);
    for (int i = addedColumn + 1; i <= addedColumn + num; i++)
    {
        string name = "Unit";
        name = string.Concat(name, i);
        TemplateField test = new TemplateField();
        test.HeaderText = name;
        test.ItemTemplate = new TemplateHandler (); // ** This line to set ItemTemplate is missing in the code you posted
        GridView1.Columns.Add(test);
       // ... Other code as you need
    }

}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: text fields are added to the columns but the issue is, when I enter 2 in txtnumber text box, Unit1 and Unit2 columns are added with text box and when I click on add button for second time text fields are displayed for Unit 3 and Unit4 columns only not for Unit1 and Unit2.

Comment: That is because you coded to add columns and I pointed what is missing for that from your code.

Comment: Thank You so much. but why the previous columns text fields are not displayed?